# apxs, apxs2 is nowhere to be found in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, debian-squeeze

I was told i have to apt-get install apache2-dev but i get:

```
apt-get install apache2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'apache2-threaded-dev' instead of 'apache2-dev'
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-threaded-dev apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common comerr-dev krb5-multidev libapr1-dev
  libaprutil1-dev libdb4.8-dev libexpat1-dev libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssrpc4 libk5crypto3 libkadm5clnt-mit7 libkadm5srv-mit7
  libkdb5-4 libkrb5-3 libkrb5-dev libkrb53 libkrb5support0 libldap2-dev libmysqlclient-dev libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0
  libpq-dev libpq5 libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libssl0.9.8 uuid-dev zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec apache2-suexec-custom doc-base krb5-doc db4.8-doc krb5-user postgresql-doc-8.4 sqlite3-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-threaded-dev comerr-dev krb5-multidev libapr1-dev libaprutil1-dev libdb4.8-dev libexpat1-dev libgssapi-krb5-2
  libgssrpc4 libk5crypto3 libkadm5clnt-mit7 libkadm5srv-mit7 libkdb5-4 libkrb5-3 libkrb5-dev libkrb5support0
  libldap2-dev libmysqlclient-dev libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev uuid-dev zlib1g-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common libkrb53 libpq5 libssl0.9.8
7 upgraded, 25 newly installed, 0 to remove and 127 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/17.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 39.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Reading changelogs... Done
```

And that's it. When issuing `dpkg -l | grep apache` i get:

```
ii  apache2                           2.2.16-6+squeeze1            Apache HTTP Server metapackage
ii  apache2-mpm-prefork               2.2.16-6+squeeze1            Apache HTTP Server - traditional non-threaded model
ii  apache2-utils                     2.2.16-6+squeeze1            utility programs for webservers
ii  apache2.2-bin                     2.2.16-6+squeeze1            Apache HTTP Server common binary files
ii  apache2.2-common                  2.2.16-6+squeeze1            Apache HTTP Server common files
ii  libapache2-mod-php5               5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny9        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
```

So it's not installed... My problem is that i don't have a apxs2 file and i'm pretty desperate at this moment. Can i just copy it to my apache_dir/sbin from another node?

P.S

After "Reading Changelog.. Done" the shell doesn't go back, i'm propmpt with a text:

```
    krb5 (1.8+dfsg~alpha1-1) unstable; urgency=low

      This version of MIT Kerberos disables DES and 56-bit RC4 by default.
      These encryption types are generally regarded as weak; defeating them
      is well within the expected resources of some attackers.  However,
      some applications, such as OpenAFS or Kerberized NFS, still rely on
      DES.  To re-enable DES support add allow_weak_crypto=true to the
      libdefaults section of /etc/krb5.conf

     -- Sam Hartman <hartmans@debian.org>  Fri, 08 Jan 2010 22:41:14 -0500

    krb5 (1.6.dfsg.4~beta1-7) unstable; urgency=low

      * In response to MIT's 2006 announcement that Kerberos 4 is at end of
        life and no longer under development, this version of the krb5 package
        removes most support for krb4.  In particular, krb4 headers are no
        longer included; applications with krb4 support cannot be built using
        libkrb5-dev.  In addition, krb4 support has been removed from the KDC
        and user utilities.  If you do not use Kerberos 4 and do not have
        krb4-config installed, you should notice no changes.  However, if you
        do use Kerberos 4, you must transition away from Kerberos 4 before
        upgrading to this version. 
  * Downgrading from this version to a previous version can  be
    difficult because of library name changes.  Please follow these
    instructions:
      - Get the libkrb53 and libkadm55 debs you want to downgrade to
      -dpkg --force-depends --remove  libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libdes425-3
        libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssrpc4 libkadm5clnt5 libkadm5srv5 libkdb5-4
        libk5crypto3
      -  At this point your system has broken Kerberos libraries
      - dpkg -i libkrb53*deb libkadm55*deb (using the debs you got above)
      - aptitude -f install to fix any other packages that may be broken
```

So i just hit Ctrl-C and go back to the shell.

Comment: Do you get back to the shell after `Reading changelogs...`?

Comment: @jpalecek please check my question again i added what happens afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Ctrl-C'd apt-get, aborting the install.

When apt-get shows changelogs, it shows them using `less` (or whatever other pager you may have set - the default is less). If it's less that's running, just hit q to continue. Hitting Ctrl-C kills less, but it also kills apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

First, it looks like your system cannot install packages. So you may need to look into that further. If your system is a low memory VPS, it is possible that you've run out of memory.

I haven't really seen `apt` terminate without any diagnostics before, but it seems to me that that is what's happening.

However, for your immediate problem, you can try to move `apxs2` from another box. First thing to do would be to use `ldd /usr/bin/apxs2` on a system that has `apache2-dev` installed. This command will give you a list of dynamic libraries that the binary needs. You can check if these libraries exist on your target system, and just copy the missing ones across as well. You can put them in `/usr/local/lib`, or modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and keep them local. I wouldn't recommend copying the libraries to `/lib` or `/usr/lib`, though. That would cause headaches in the long run. This is not really a solution, but it may help in the short term.

Comment: thanks for the elaborated answer. I added what happens after apt-get fails. I should have included it in my initial question but i thought it's not related. Can you please take a look and tell me if you think it's still connected to lack of memory?

Comment: Low memory issues should result in _some_ sort of log - either an error from APT, or a bus error message, or a OOM dump in dmesg.